# MySQL logic count operation

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I ran three SQL queries in MySQL, but there is a logic problem.

```
select count(*) from keeper where code!=''; -- result1=2893193
select count(*) from keeper where code=''; -- result2=66
select count(*) from keeper; -- result3=3481069
```

I expected that `result1 + result2 = result3`, but in fact, `result1 + result2 < result3`. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

Using `IS NOT NULL` AND `IS NULL` in addition to `=''` will make sure you get all rows that are both just empty like you are looking for already or have the column set as NULL

```
SELECT count(*) FROM keeper WHERE code!='' OR code IS NOT NULL;
SELECT count(*) FROM keeper WHERE code = '' OR code IS NULL
```

Comment: I have never been able to have `IS NULL` return values that are just empty which is why I always put both.  It is not needed really with the `IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Always use `IS NuLL` ans `IS NOT NULL` to get exact empty and non empty records respectively. it checks both empty and null values.

Try below:

```
select count(*) from keeper where code is NULL;
```

AND

```
select count(*) from keeper where code is NOT NULL
```

Alternatively you can use :

```
select  count(*) from keeper where LENGTH(COALESCE(code ,'')) = 0
```

will give you all records with an 'empty' value for code , treating NULL as empty.

Answer (score 0):

[Three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) attacks!

NULL and "" are two different things. NULL is considered to be neither equal nor not equal to `""` and so neither of your queries will ever return it. I'd guess that the extra 500,000 records returned by your third query have `code` set to NULL. You can test for null fields using `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. If you do:

```
SELECT count(*) from keeper where code!='';
SELECT count(*) from keeper where code='';
SELECT count(*) from keeper where code IS NULL;
```

Those three results should add up to the total number of rows in your table.

Comment: `NULL and "" are two different things` - unless you have a brain-dead DBMS like Oracle which can't tell the difference :-) Sorry, can never miss an opportunity to bag their bizarre decision back in the day.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.   select count(*) from keeper where code!=''
2.   select count(*) from keeper where code=''
2.5. select count(*) from keeper where code is null
3.   select count(*) from keeper
```

Note the one inserted before `3`. NULL is considered a separate case from any other value, being neither equal to, nor not equal to, any other value (including another NULL).